# Grouping in MongoDb using aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am a beginner to MongoDB and I found the Aggregate function hard to understand.

I read many topics and tried many things, however I couldn't get the results I am looking for.

Actually, I have two schema as:

1) Faculty.js

```
const FacultySchema = new Schema({

    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }

});
```

2) Semester.js

```
const SemesterSchema = new Schema({

    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    faculty: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'faculties'
    }   

});
```

Semester collection

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5bf82da745209d0d48a91b62"),
    "name": "1st Semester",
    "faculty": ObjectId("5bf7f39a1972dd0b6c74de7d"),
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5bf8c3f945209d0d48a91b63"),
    "name": "2nd Semester",
    "faculty": ObjectId("5bf7f39a1972dd0b6c74de7d"),
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5bf8c3fe45209d0d48a91b64"),
    "name": "3rd Semester",
    "faculty": ObjectId("5bf7f39a1972dd0b6c74de7d"),
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5bf8c40345209d0d48a91b65"),
    "name": "4th Semester",
    "faculty": ObjectId("5bf7f39a1972dd0b6c74de7d"),
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

What I want to group is all those semesters as an array having same faculty id in one place.
 Something like:

```
[
{faculty: "BBA", semesters: ['first', 'second', 'third']},
{faculty: "BCA", semesters: ['first', 'second', 'third']}
];
```

How can I achieve this??

Comment: Could you post the sample documents from the `Faculty` and the `Semesters` collection

Comment: Some samples of faculties collection:    { "_id" : ObjectId("5bf82da745209d0d48a91b62"), "name" : "1st Semester", "faculty" : ObjectId("5bf7f39a1972dd0b6c74de7d"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bf8c3f945209d0d48a91b63"), "name" : "2nd Semester", "faculty" : ObjectId("5bf7f39a1972dd0b6c74de7d"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bf8c3fe45209d0d48a91b64"), "name" : "3rd Semester", "faculty" : ObjectId("5bf7f39a1972dd0b6c74de7d"), "__v" : 0 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5bf8c40345209d0d48a91b65"), "name" : "4th Semester", "faculty" : ObjectId("5bf7f39a1972dd0b6c74de7d"), "__v" : 0 }

Comment: Here I can populate 'faculty' to access all fields in faculties collection. What I wanted is for all distinct faculties I have to find array of semesters having same faculty id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) aggregation to first find the distinct `faculties` and then [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to get the `names` of the `faculties` from the Faculties collection

```
Semester.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$faculty",
    "semesters": { "$push": "$name" }
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "faculties",
    "let": { "facultyId": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$_id", "$$facultyId"] }}}
    ],
    "as": "faculty"
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "semesters": 1, "faculty": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$faculty.name", 0] }
  }}
])
```

Or you can use [**`$lookup`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) first and then [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)ing the distinct `names`

```
Semester.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "Faculty",
    "let": { "facultyId": "$_id" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": ["$_id", "$$facultyId"] }}}
    ],
    "as": "faculty"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$faculty" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$faculty.name",
    "semesters": { "$push": "$name" }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "semesters": 1, "faculty": "$_id", "_id": 0 }
  }}
])
```

Comment: This worked as expected. Thanks @Anthony Winzlet. Where can I get full description to understand this query clearly.

Comment: @John You can read the documentation from the link I have posted in the answer. For the `$group` and `$lookup` aggregation